# Font size in mirt plots

Tags: r, plot, lattice

I'm trying to increase font size in `mirt` plots, however, so far I'm able to increase size of ticks only:

```
library(mirt)
x <- mirt(Science, 1, SE=TRUE)
plot(x)
```

[image]

```
plot(x, scales = list(cex = c(1.4)))
```

[image]

How can I increase size of the axis and main title? I tried to add `xlab = list(cex = 1.4)`, however I'm getting an error:

```
Error in xyplot.formula(score ~ Theta, plt, ylim = c(sum(mins) - ybump_full,  : 
  formal argument "xlab" matched by multiple actual arguments
```

**EDIT: **
Some parts can be increased with `trellis.par.set()` as suggested by @user20650, however it does not include font size of legend.

```
trellis.par.set(par.xlab.text = list(cex = 1.4), par.ylab.text = list(cex = 1.4))
plot(x, type = "trace", facet_items = FALSE, scales = list(cex = 1.4), 
     par.strip.text = list(cex = 1.4), main = FALSE)
```

[image]

Moreover, this does not have impact on the following plot:

```
plot(x, type = "infoSE", facet_items = FALSE, scales = list(cex = 1.4), 
     par.strip.text = list(cex = 1.4), main = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: The plot function seems to have the `xlab` hardcoded to "xlab = expression(theta)"; I suppose you could update the global parameters i.e. `trellis.par.set(par.xlab.text=list(cex=10),par.main.text=list(cex=10)) ; plot(x)`. See `trellis.par.get()` for things that can be updated. Whether this is the best way or not??

Comment: This works pretty well. Thank you very much :)

Comment: I'm just wondering whether it is possible to increase font size of all elements with a general command (including e.g. legends etc.)?

Comment: Why don't you open a ticket at the authors' [github](https://github.com/philchalmers/mirt/issues)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set parameters globally with `trellis.par.set` or pass to the individual plot using the `par.settings` parameter. `trellis.par.get()` can be used to get a list of the names of the objects that can be updated.

So for example the following can be used to update specific parameters within a plot

```
plot(x, type = "trace", 
     par.settings=list(
       par.xlab.text=list(cex=3, col="red"),
       par.main.text=list(cex=2)))
```

Or to update globally use

```
trellis.par.set(par.xlab.text=list(cex=3, col="red"),
                par.main.text=list(cex=2)
                )
```

Using `grid.pars=list(cex=3))` seems to update all text sizes

Comment: `grid.pars = list(cex = 3)` does exactly what I wanted. Thank you!